# Is my RB67 back missing a part?

Tags: film, medium-format, mamiya, film-cameras

Just got an RB67 Pro with Pro S 120 film back. In the photo below, there is (I think) a little piece missing that should hold the film spool in place (where the arrow points to).

[image]

Right now, the film kinda wiggles around when loaded. There is something on the other side to hold the empty reel in solidly.

Just wondering what this potential part is so I can find one.

Comment: What is the source of your loded film spool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the name of the part, but based on this photo of a Pro S 120 module, you are missing a part where you suspect you are.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't find an image of a back with this exact angle. Thanks, looks like that little white piece is missing to seat the film canister properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need an empty 120 spool. The film goes from one spool to the other when shooting. For a new roll, simply move the now empty spool to the receiving end and load a new roll.

A local film shop/lab should be able to give you one for free.

Comment: It sounds like the OP already has an empty spool. But the loaded film spool does not seem to be seating solidly enough.

Comment: what’s the other side look like?

Comment: @Hueco The area circled with an arrow pointing to it in image included in the OP is for the loaded film spool, not the take-up spool.